# WebGL is it possible to emulate an asynchronous call to gl.finish()

Tags: webgl

WebGL is nice and asynchronous in that you can send off a long list of rendering commands without waiting for them to complete.  However, if for some reason you do need to wait for the rendering to complete, you have to do it synchronously with `gl.finish()`.  Surely it would be better if `gl.finish` accepted a callback and returned immediately?

**Question:** Is there any way to emulate this reliably?

**Usage case:** I am rendering a large number of vertices to a large off-screen canvas and then using `drawImage` to copy sections of this large canvas to small canvases on the page. I don't actually use `gl.finish()` but `drawImage()` seems to have the same effect. In my application, re-rendering is only triggered when the user performs an action (e.g. clicking a button), and it may take several hundred milliseconds.  It would be nice if during rendering the browser was still responsive allowing scrolling etc.  I am looking in particular for a Chrome solution, though something that also works in Firefox and Safari would be good.

**Possible (bad) answer:** You could try and estimate how long rendering is going to take and then set a timeout that begins with the call to `gl.finish()`.  However, reliably doing this estimation for all sizes of vertex buffer and all users is going to be pretty tricky and inaccurate.

**Possible (non-)answer:** `requestAnimationFrame` does what I'm looking for...it doesn't though, does it?

**Possible answer in 2018:** Perhaps the `ImageBitmap` API solves this problem - see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/transferToImageBitmap#Examples).

Comment: There is no way you could render it from same page, with 'async' gl.finish() as there is no async version. If drawing off-screen image is something considered 'heavy' then you could use Web Worker to generate it, and then just postMessage back with such image, and draw it to canvas. That would slightly save performance, still drawing have to be sync.
Reducing resolution of canvas might speed up it as well.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs - rendering an image from a web worker would be asynchronous but it would be using the CPU not the GPU, so it will be much slower. (You cant access WebGL from WebWorkers.)

Comment: I've been talking more about canvas 2d context, as you mentioned `drawImage`.

Answer (score 5):

You've already partially hit on your answer: `drawImage()` does indeed have finish-like behavior in that it forces all outstanding drawing commands to complete before it reads back the image data. The problem is that even if `gl.finish()` did what you wanted it to, wait for rendering to complete, you would still have the same behavior using it as you do now. The main thread would be blocked while the rendering finishes, interrupting the user's ability to interact with the page.

Ideally what you would want in this scenario is some sort of callback that indicates when a set of draw commands have been completed without actually blocking to wait for them. Unfortunately no such callback exists (and it would be surprisingly difficult to provide one, given the way the browser's internals work!)

A decent middle-ground in your case may be to do some intelligent estimations of when you feel the image may be ready. For example, once you have dispatched your draw call spin through 3 or 4 `requestAnimationFrame`s before you call `drawImage`. If you consistently observe it taking longer (10 frames?) then spin for longer. This would allow users to continue interacting with the page normally and either produce no delay when doing the draw image, because the contents have finished rendering, or much less delay because you do the synchronous step mid-way through the render. Depending on the intended usage of your site non-realtime rendering could probably even stand to spin for a full second or so before presenting.

This certainly isn't a perfect solution, and I wish I had a better answer for you. Perhaps WebGL will gain the ability to query this type of status in the future, because it would be valuable in cases like yours, but for now this is likely the best you can do.

Comment: I've just read your [webgl 2.0 post](http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/09/whats-coming-in-webgl-20.html).  Would I be right in thinking that sync objects would solve the problem here?